# Receiving hexadecimal values from socket instead of strings on SocketServer

Tags: android, python, sockets, encoding, character-encoding

I opened a socket between an Android app and a python server. The combination is that the Server listens, and android connects to the Server.

Here is the server code. The problematic part takes place in the definition of `handle` :

```
import SocketServer
from time import sleep
import sys

HOST = '192.168.56.1'
PORT = 2000

class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
    try:
        while(1):
            sleep(0.03)
            data = self.rfile.readline().strip()

            print data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

class SimpleServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)


server = SimpleServer((HOST, PORT), SingleTCPHandler)
try:
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

The connection is established normally, and the Android app sends the following data to the socket:

```
'0:0'
```

But the data is received on the Server as:

```
'\x000\x00:\x000\x00'
```

The variable that receives the data is:

```
data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
```

and printing gives the regular format:

```
In [2]: print data
0:0
```

I didn't manage to step into the `print` function with pdb to see what it does.
I'm looking for a way to convert the `'\x000\x00:\x000\x00'` to `'0:0'`.

Please advise on a way to convert the variable. You are welcome to comment/criticize the whole implementation. This is my first project in dealing with sockets so i don't know the pitfalls.

**Update**

This was the original Android code:

```
String podaci = "0:0";
public void Socketic() throws IOException {

    Socket mojSocket = new Socket(urlServer, port);

    DataOutputStream izlazdata = new DataOutputStream(
            mojSocket.getOutputStream());
    while (podaci != "end") {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        izlazdata.writeChars(podaci);
        izlazdata.flush();
    }
    izlazdata.close();
    mojSocket.close();
};
```

And the problem was, as you suspected in:

```
izlazdata.writeChars(podaci);
```

`writeChars` uses the method `writeChar`. The API documentation for `writeChar` states:

> Writes a char to the underlying output stream as a 2-byte value, high byte first...

The two bytes represent the 16bits which UTF-16 uses for encoding.

When we changed it to everything started working:

```
izlazdata.writeBytes(podaci);
```

**Update**

Based on the answers given, here is how the unwanted string is to be interpreted in terms of characters.

[image]

This solves my concrete problem, however, if someone would give a more generic solution to what happend here so that a larger lesson can be learned.
If not, i will accept Esailijas answer in a few days.

Comment: Try sending "0:0" instead of '0:0'?

Comment: I guess the problem is in your sender, it seems to send the characters as 16 bit quantities. Can you show the sender code?

Comment: post the android code. it is possible you send each character as a string, possibliy including a eof char with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show the code happening Android but it strongly seems like it's sending data in UTF-16BE. You should specify the encoding on the Android end. The characters are not hexadecimal literally, but because the NUL character is unprintable, python shows `\x00` instead.

Another option is to decode it:

```
self.rfile.readline().decode("utf_16_be").strip()
```

note that the result of this is an unicode string.

Comment: We will test the code tomorrow, and paste the results together with the old code and the changed one. Could you please explain what was conceptually the source of the problem, and why is the `:` not also treated as a hex?

Comment: @Alan forget about hex, there isn't any hex as I said in my answer. That's just a way to display character that cannot be printed, in many other programs you would have seen `0:0` without knowing that there were 4 NULs hiding in there, and never noticed this major bug. I don't know who suggested `writeBytes` but that's completely accidental - it isn't even possible to change `writeChars(podaci)` to `writeBytes(podaci)`. You'd need to change `podaci` as well, and you didn't show that.

Comment: Updated the code with `podaci`, and question based on your answer. I was misinterpreting how character were grouped in the received string. Also added the reason why I think `writeBytes` fixed the problem.

Comment: @Alan `podaci` is a `String`.. how is it possible to call `writeBytes(String)` ? If it takes a string, then it implicitly uses another encoding. In any case, in python code, you need to call `.decode()`. Otherwise, even in the `writeBytes` case, you will have bugs with non-ASCII characters. Might as well use `writeChars` and `decode('utf_16_be')`

Comment: The API for `writeBytes(String s)` states: `Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits`. Here is a link on the subject:  [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/186074/java-developer-SCJD/certification/writeUTF-writeBytes)

Comment: @Alan So it implicitly encodes to ASCII. Note that no language can be written completely in ASCII so when using this solution, and writing `résumé`, will be converted to `r?esum?` because `é` is not in ASCII.